# Approximation of $\sqrt{1+wi}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion, binomial-theorem

How can  $\sqrt{1+wi}$ be approximated? where $-\infty<w<\infty$;

My aim here is getting rid of the square root.

I've tried binomial, Maclurin and Taylor series around various points. but they dont work for large $w$ .

Comment: Do cases? If $|w|<1$ then use the binomial series. If $|w|<1$ write $\sqrt{1+wi}=\sqrt{w i} \sqrt{1+1/wi }$.

Comment: Have you tried transforming it into $\sqrt{i}\cdot\sqrt{w-i}$, to me it seems that will help.

Comment: $w$ may take too large values, so binomial series does not work.

Comment: if the binomial series is concerned, your suggestion cant work for large w.

Answer (score 1):

The value is of the square root is

$$\sqrt{1+iw}=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{1+w^2}+1}2}+i\frac{w}{\sqrt{2(\sqrt{1+w^2}+1)}}$$

however, this has even more square roots, only that now they are of positive real numbers.

Comment: My purpose is getting rid of the square root.